Pythagorean triangles with non rectilinear
Does there exist a Pythagorean triple whose corner is non-rectilinear with axes, yet all three vertices are on integer coordinates?
The question was closed due to "lack of context". The context is 2D Cartesian coordinate systems. I suppose you could ask the question about non-Cartesian coordinate systems, but all responses correctly assumed the question was intended for Cartesian systems.
Or maybe context means why is it relevant to me personally. Well, personally, I don't see how that affects the question in any way. I happened to want to generate examples of triangles with easy perimeter length calculations, but that hardly seems relevant to the question. In fact, no one needed to know that in order to discuss or answer the question. So I am confused as to how this helps the question, but being a good net citizen I have added it as requested.

Well if it is not, you can always rotate it a little, right?!

To be clear: Are you asking for a (non-axis-aligned) right triangle with integer-length sides, whose vertices have integer coordinates?

If @Blue is right, you can do what JoséCarlosSantos suggests! For instance, start with a $3-4-5$ triangle. Of course, rotating this through anything but a multiple of $90^\circ$ gives you non-lattice points. So scale it using a Pythagorean hypotenuse! (eg by a factor of $17$). Now you can rotate it; in this case, you get the triangle with vertices $(0,0)$, $(45,24)$ and $(-32,60)$, which has integer sides.

@Blue, yes, that is what I meant, I now realize I was somewhat unclear about integer-length sides.

Comments do not seem to accept pasted pictures.   This is the triangle that Chris Lewis described.

